# use command yum in my server Centos 5.8

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, yum

I wana install ffmpeg-php in my server but.
I can't use command yum in my server Centos 5.8.
There is somme one to help me plz ??

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide more info?

You can't use yum because:

- You don't have privileges to use it
- You are getting some error... Can you post this error if there is any?